# Can benzene damage rubber or other materials or adhesives used in tire production?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

In this article, "[Bridgestone/Firestone, Inc. and Ford Motor Company: How a Product Safety Crisis Ended a Hundred-Year Relationship](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237812181_BridgestoneFirestone_Inc_and_Ford_Motor_Company_How_a_Product_Safety_Crisis_Ended_a_Hundred-Year_Relationship)" the article states, "Industry observers have speculated [that]... a disproportionate amount of Benzene was added to the rubber compound which affected the adhesion in the years to follow," and "Excessive use of benzene can damage the quality of the tire material."

Is it true that too much Benzene can damage tires, either the rubber, the adhesives, or other materials used in tire manufacturing?

Comment: In the days when benzene was a cheap lab solvent and its toxicity wasn't well known, chemists used it to shrink the rubber stoppers in bottles and flasks as it infiltrates and drastically changes the properties of rubber. So the answer is probably "yes".

Comment: Rubber cement used to be simply rubber dissolved in benzene... now, safer alipahtic solvents are used. Benzene is an excellent solvent for isoprene.